# Inaccurate results with MySQL Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query created by my PHP script . The query executes successfully without any errors, but with results i am not expecting. I want the rows in the result of this query to contain all the three keywords (3D,design,PAG). But, Right now it returns results even if  one key word is found. How can the query be Modified ?

```
SELECT ID
FROM  `catiascripts` 
WHERE  `ID` LIKE  '%3D%'
OR  `ScriptName` LIKE  '%3D%'
OR  `ScriptApplication` LIKE  '%3D%'
OR  `ScriptDescription` LIKE  '%3D%'
OR  `Customer` LIKE  '%3D%'
AND ID
IN (

SELECT ID
FROM  `catiascripts` 
WHERE  `ID` LIKE  '%design%'
OR  `ScriptName` LIKE  '%design%'
OR  `ScriptApplication` LIKE  '%design%'
OR  `ScriptDescription` LIKE  '%design%'
OR  `Customer` LIKE  '%design%'
)
AND ID
IN (

SELECT ID
FROM  `catiascripts` 
WHERE  `ID` LIKE  '%PAG%'
OR  `ScriptName` LIKE  '%PAG%'
OR  `ScriptApplication` LIKE  '%PAG%'
OR  `ScriptDescription` LIKE  '%PAG%'
OR  `Customer` LIKE  '%PAG%'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: You need parentheses. Group the ORs together.

Comment: You don't need subqueries for this. Use `WHERE (ID LIKE '%3D' OR ...) AND (ID LIKE '%design%' OR ...) AND (ID LIKE '%PAG%' OR ...)`

Comment: BTW, do you really have strings like `design` in the ID field? You don't use a number for the ID?

Comment: Ofcourse, i use a number for the ID field. But, since i was testing different sql queries, i did not mind the ID column with some arbitrary value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need brackets on your `and/or` expression. You're violating MySQL's order-of-operations, therefore you must enforce your own with appropriate `()`.

`and` has a higher priority than `or`, so your query:

```
SELECT   p OR q OR r AND x OR y OR z ...
```

is being executed as

```
SELECT p OR q OR (r AND x) OR y OR Z
```

You want

```
SELECT (p OR q OR r) AND (x OR y OR Z) AND (...)
```

Relevant doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: I hesitate to call it a "violation" but I did upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Marked this as answer because it is informative. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID
FROM `catiascripts` 
WHERE (
       `ID` LIKE '%3D%'
    OR `ScriptName` LIKE '%3D%'
    OR `ScriptApplication` LIKE '%3D%'
    OR `ScriptDescription` LIKE '%3D%'
    OR `Customer` LIKE '%3D%'
)
AND (
       `ID` LIKE '%design%'
    OR `ScriptName` LIKE '%design%'
    OR `ScriptApplication` LIKE '%design%'
    OR `ScriptDescription` LIKE '%design%'
    OR `Customer` LIKE '%design%'
)
AND (
       `ID` LIKE '%PAG%'
    OR `ScriptName` LIKE '%PAG%'
    OR `ScriptApplication` LIKE '%PAG%'
    OR `ScriptDescription` LIKE '%PAG%'
    OR `Customer` LIKE '%PAG%'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```